# (NIP Theory) If $I$ is an endless indiscernible sequence and $J$ is a Morley sequence of $\lim(I)$ then $I+J^*$ is indiscernible.

Tags: logic, model-theory

In an NIP theory, show that if $I$ is an endless indiscernible sequence and $J$ is a Morley sequence in the type $\lim(I)$, then $I+J^*$ is indiscernible.

Here, $J^*$ means the sequence $J$ with the order reversed.

As we are working in a NIP theory, the type $p=\lim(I)$ is a global complete type.

I know I can reduce this problem to prove that for any $i_1,\dots,i_{n+1}\in I$ and $j_1,\dots,j_m\in J^*$ there exists $j'\in J^*$ (whose index in $J^*$ is less than the index of $j_1$) such that $$i_1,\dots,i_n,i_{n+1},j_1,\dots,j_m\equiv i_1,\dots,i_n,j',j_1,\dots,j_m.$$
I also know that I can assume that $J$ is $I$-indiscernible.

I don't exactly know how to attack this problem. I think I am missing something. Some hints or references will be appreciated.

Comment: It's good practice to include the question you're asking in the body of the question, not just the title. I edited to make this change and improve grammar. Welcome to Math Stackexchange, if you are a new user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with your reduction, but you'll find it easier to "move" elements of $J^*$ into $I$, rather than the reverse. Also, it's easier to work formula-by-formula than to realize the complete type all at once.

First, let's observe the following.

**Claim:** For any formula $\varphi$, any $i_1<\dots<i_n$ in $I$, and any $j'<j_1<\dots<j_m$ in $J^*$, if $$\varphi(i_1,\dots,i_n,j',j_1,\dots,j_m)$$ then there exists $i'>i_n$ in $I$ such that $$\varphi(i_1,\dots,i_n,i',j_1,\dots,j_m).$$

*Proof:* By the definition of Morley sequence, $j'$ realizes $\lim(I)$ over $I$ and $j_1,\dots,j_m$. By the definition of $\lim(I)$, any formula in this type is realized by an element of $I$ (in fact, by a whole end segment). $\square$

Ok, now fix some $i_1<\dots<i_n$ in $I$ and $j'<j_1<\dots<j_m$ in $J^*$ and assume $$\varphi(i_1,\dots,i_n,j_1,\dots,j_m).$$ Applying the claim $m$ times, we obtain $i_{n+1},\dots,i_{n+m}$ with $i_1<\dots<i_n < i_{n+1} < \dots < i_{n+m}$ such that $$\varphi(i_1,\dots,i_n,i_{n+1},\dots,i_{n+m}).$$
By indiscernibility of $I$, it follows that for any $i_1'<\dots,i'_{n+m}$ in $I$, $$\varphi(i_1',\dots,i_{n+m}').$$
Since $\varphi$ was an arbitrary formula, we  conclude that for any $i_1'<\dots,i'_{n+m}$ in $I$, $\text{tp}(i_1,\dots,i_n,j_1,\dots,j_m) = \text{tp}(i_1',\dots,i'_{n+m})$. Since $(i_1,\dots,i_n,j_1,\dots,j_m)$ was an arbitrary increasing sequence from $I+J^*$, we conclude that any such sequence has the same type, and hence $I+J^*$ is indiscernible.

Comment: I am having a problem proving the statement of the int, at first I thought it will be an easy compactness argument but the problem is that $I$ is not definable or type-definable. I tried to use that you can ask $i'$ to satisfy $p(i_1,\dots,i_n,x)=tp(i_1,\dots,i_n,i_k)$ for some $i_k>i_n$ and try to move it using an isomorphism of the monster model, but that might move $(j_1,\dots,j_m)$.

Comment: Sorry I think I was not clear, I know how to prove the statement with the hint you gave me. I am now trying to prove the hint. I thought it should be easy with compactness to prove that if we are on the situation of the hint, then exists $i'\in I$ such that $$i_1,\dots,i_n,i',j_1,\dots,j_m\equiv i_1,\dots,i_n,j',j_1,\dots,j_m$$ but I do not know how to ensure that the element is in $I$ because $I$ could be non-definable

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I am very lost with this problem. What I was trying to ask is why it suffices to prove the statement of the hint. That is, I am not able to prove that if I can find $i'$ for each formula (and parameters) then $I+J^*$ is indiscernible. My idea was to prove that if I can find $i'$ for each formula (with the $i_k$ and $j_l$ fixed) then I can find $i'\in I$ satisfying all the formulas at the same time

Comment: @UserUser I've edited my answer (and removed my previous comments, since the substance of them is now contained in the answer).